# Vector space exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

**The set of all triples of real numbers $(x,y,z)$ with the operations $(x,y,z)+(x´,y´,z´)=(x+x´,y+y´,z+z´$) and $k(x,y,z)=(kx,y,z)$.
Show if the set of objects given with operations of addition and scalar multiplication is a vector space.**

According to the solutions axiom 8)$(k+l)u=ku+lu$ fails.

However I cannot understand why since $ku=(kx,y,z)$ and $lu=(lx,y,z)$, therefore $(k+l)u==ku+lu$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $(k+l)(x,y,z) = ((k+l)x,y,z) = (kx+lx,y,z)$

Comment: But $k(x, y, z) + l(x, y, z) = (kx, y, z) + (lx, y, z) = (kx + lx, 2 y, 2 z)$.

Comment: But $k(x, y, z) + l(x, y, z) = (kx, y, z) + (lx, y, z) = (kx + lx, 2 y, 2 z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Say $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$ and $k=l=1.$ Then $(k+l)(x,y,z)=2(1,1,1)=(2,1,1),$ but $k(x,y,z)+l(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)+(1,1,1)=(2,2,2).$

Answer (score 1):

In a vector space, $0v=0$ for all $v$, but in your space $0(1,1,1)=(0,1,1) \ne 0$.